# how to add events to a class from data('events') in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to remove and add some class to a element as shown below

```
$("#"+obj.id+" div.treeclick").removeClass("ui-icon-radio-off").removeClass("tree-leaf").addClass("tree-minus").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s");
```

now I want to bind events that are there for class tree-minus so I use the following line

```
$("#"+obj.id+" div.treeclick").removeClass("ui-icon-radio-off").removeClass("tree-leaf").addClass("tree-minus").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s").bind($(".tree-minus").data('events'));
```

but I got an error saying " Object has no method 'apply' " ,how can I add events that I'll get from $("tree-minus").data('events')

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#" + obj.id + " div.treeclick")
    .removeClass("ui-icon-radio-off tree-leaf")
    .addClass("tree-minus ui-icon-triangle-1-s");

$("#" + obj.id).on($(this).data('events'), 'div.treeclick', function() {

});
```

or

```
   $("#" + obj.id + " div.treeclick")
        .removeClass("ui-icon-radio-off tree-leaf")
        .addClass("tree-minus ui-icon-triangle-1-s")
        .on($(this).data('events'), 'div.treeclick', function() {
            alert('event binded');
        });
```

#### Note

You don't need to call `addClass()` and `removeClass()` separately for each class, just use comma separated values.

#### Why you need `.on()` delegete event

Because, when you change class of an element it treats as new element, not exists previously in the DOM, so it needs delegate event.

---

#### According to your comment

```
$("#" + obj.id + " div.treeclick")
    .removeClass("ui-icon-radio-off tree-leaf")
    .addClass("tree-minus ui-icon-triangle-1-s");

$("#" + obj.id).on($('.tree-minus').data('events'), '.tree-minus.ui-icon-triangle-1-s', function() {

});
​
```

Comment: I want to bind the handlers that are there on the class "tree-minus ui-icon-triangle-1-s" for the same events,how to do this?

Comment: The control is not coming out of that statement,I think It's in infinite loop.

Comment: In the above code is function(){} is an handler for the events on tree-minus ?

Comment: @pavi yes, that is an handler function() {}

Comment: `$("#"+obj.id+" div.treeclick").removeClass("ui-icon-radio-off").removeClass("tree-leaf").addClass("tree-minus").addClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-s").bind("click",onClickOnTreeMinus);`              onClickOnTreeMinus is the handler                    I used the above to bind the event.What I wanted is dynamically to find all the events on the element '.tree-minus' and bind it,but if I use .on() it's going to infinite loop.Thanks for you help.